# How to send EOF in line mode of telnet

Tags: escaping, telnet

I'm new to linux socket programming,after connected to the remote server

```
telnet x.x.x.x xxxx
```

How can I send a EOF character to the remote server through telnet?

these character escape doesn't seem to work

```
^D

^]D

`^]D`
```

and how to terminate this telnet connection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In typical *ix telnet, you should be able to hold control and press ] (right square bracket) to get to the telnet prompt. From there, you can type 'quit' to exit telnet entirely.

The client should be telling you this when it first starts up. For instance, on my box:

```
~$ telnet localhost 2050
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

That last line is the pertinent one. Its using a caret ^ to represent 'hold control'. :)

It is possibly worthwhile to type 'help' to see what your other options are when you're at the telnet prompt.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the way to fire up the pe

Comment: prompt mode. But unfortunately it doesn't work in my machine(ubuntu 10 lucid). When I hit ctl+] it gives me  ^]]C

Comment: I just noticed it may be caused by the ipad terminal client that I'm using it called Prompt by Panic. Because when I hit ctl in the virtue keyboard, and it works.

Comment: That'd do it! Glad you figured out where the problem was. Its never fun when it there's another program in there to throw one off track. :)

Answer (score 0):

`telnet x.x.x.x xxxx <<EOF` might be something.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, is there a way to do it in the line mode?